# Comparing GDP contractions between Russia and US

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp

I was reading [Rogoff's piece](https://www.project-syndicate.org/commentary/russia-bleak-economic-prospects-by-kenneth-rogoff-2017-07#comments) on the Russia's economic outlook, and in a paragraph, he states

> The shock to the real economy has been severe, with Russia suffering a decline in output in 2015 and 2016 comparable to what the United States experienced during its 2008-2009 financial crisis, with the contraction in GDP totaling about 4%.

I'm wondering how did they reach this figure. I was trying to redo the calculations, this time with [OECD data](https://data.oecd.org/gdp/gross-domestic-product-gdp.htm) on GDP, but none of the figures obtained are comparable - I just did $GDP_{t+1}/GDP_{t}=1+gr$ For Russia, I got 6-7%, and USA 2-3%,  depending whether we use GDP or GDP per capita.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rogoff's article (at least current version) the first sentence you quote [links to IMF's World Economic Outlook Database](https://www.imf.org/external/pubs/ft/weo/2017/01/weodata/index.aspx).

My guess is that when he is referring to *output* he means *Gross domestic product, constant prices*. Looking up the numbers in the database we have 63038.4 billions of 2011 rubles in 2014 and 61097.5 in 2016 which translates to 3.1% decline (negative growth).

If I use per capita numbers than that also gives 3.1% decline which I guess is "comparable" to 4% decline.

Comment: So, Rogoff is using the real GDP in Rubles, and I was using nominal GDP in Dollars. Thanks ;)